# locating a square root element with square in a free subgroup

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily countable discrete) which contains a free subgroup $F=F_2=\langle a, b\rangle$, denote $H=\langle a, b^2\rangle$, and assume that the centralizer of $F$ inside of $G$ is trivial, i.e., $C_G(F)=\{e\}$.

Suppose $e\neq g\in G$, and $gag^{-1},~ gb^2g^{-1}\in H$, is it true that $gbg^{-1}\in F$?

Any hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cuestion thus is: is it true that $\;N_G(H)\le N_G(F)\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, exactly, my motivation is to deal with $G=SO(3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just take an HNN-extension. For example, take $G$ as follows. $$G=\langle x, y, t; txt^{-1}=x, ty^2t^{-1}=y^2\rangle$$ Then $tyt^{-1}$ is a $t$-reduced word and so is not contained in $\langle x,y\rangle$ by [Britton's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension#Britton.27s_Lemma).

*Note: the centraliser of $H=\langle x, y\rangle$ is trivial here, so this answers your question. However, the centraliser of $t$ is not trivial. If you want to change this then you could the relations I gave with the relations $txt^{-1}=x^2$ and $ty^2t^{-1}=y^4$, or some similar choices which don't correspond to finite-order element of $\operatorname{Out}(F_2)$ (or rather, don't restrict to such a finite order element on either $x$ or $y$).*

Comment: @Thanks, I asked this question with the motivation to deal with the case $G=SO(3)$, so I extract the ''points" to ask this more general question. Now it is clear this reformulation is not as successful as I expect:(  Anyway, thanks again! But may you consider the case $G=SO(3)$, since in this case, it seems all known examples for choosing $a, b$ to be free, the $t$ you constructed is identity matrix.

Comment: @ougao I am not sure about $\operatorname{SO}(3)$. Anything I say would just be clutching at straws. (Although I would suggest changing the relators to $txt^{-1}=U(x, y)$ and $ty^2t^{-1}=V(x, y)$ and seeing if this bears any fruit. You could try taking $U=xy^2xy^3x\cdots xy^n$ and $V=xy^{n+1}x\cdots xy^{2n}$. This group is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n>>1$, but I don't know if it would lie in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$. Worth a shot though.)

Comment: I guess no, since it is not clear how could you choose $x,y$ free and the trace of $u, v$ is equal to $x,y$ respectively.

Comment: @ougao But it *is* linear over $\mathbb{Z}$, I just don't know the dimension of the relevant matrices (and I wonder if anyone in the whole world does!). So there is a way of picking matrices with $x$, $y$ free and where the traces match up (if you pick $u$ and $v$ to have the form I gave above). The issue is the dimension. And also being in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$.

Comment: @ougao Oh, also, you should also ask this altered question as a new question, linking back to this one. You are more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: could you give me a reference for the "way" you mentioned to construct such $x,y$? I still do not know your motivation to choose such $u,v$.

Comment: @ user1729, do you mind help asking this relevant question you mentioned above, since as I said above, I do not understand your example clearly.

Comment: @ougao The motivation behind my picking those specific words is because they are "small cancellation" words. I believe these words first appeared in a paper of Rips entitled "Subgroups of small cancellation groups". See the last chapter of the book "Combinatorial group theory" for the background on small cancellation theory. The problem is...it is a really recent, and really massive, result that small cancellation groups are linear over $\mathbb{Z}$. I was just wondering if you could come up with a nice way without me telling you all this (which really just clouds the issue).

Comment: got it, thanks, I asked it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614084/locating-a-square-root-element-with-square-in-a-free-subgroup-ii